# Take all classes from .owl file and compare with another classes using Java

Tags: java, jena, ontology

I already generated an ont.owl file using Jena. Then first I need to take all the classes to the array list which are contain the ontology. secondly I will give another classes(terms) using my code and check whether these classes contain generated ontology or not. following is the code up to now.

```
 m.read("http://localhost/myontofile/ont.owl");
      ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = m.listClasses();
      while (classes.hasNext()) {
        OntClass takeclasses = (OntClass) classes.next();
        String ontcls = takeclasses.getLocalName().toString();

        ArrayList<String> listiter = new ArrayList<String>();
        listiter.add(ontcls);
        System.out.println("classes: " + listiter); ----------????

    ///////////////////////////////////////                   

ArrayList<String> tempTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
      String aTerm = terms.get(i) ;
      tempTerms.add(aTerm);
    }
    terms.add("Information");
    terms.add("Video Information");
    terms.add("Video Price Information");
    terms.add("Video Maximum Price Information");
    terms.add("Action Video Price Information");

    for(int i=0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
      if (listiter.equals(terms.get(i))==true) {        
        System.out.println("ok");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("no");
      }
    }
  }
```

Result is always come to else ("no") part. "classes" give out put as only one class. What are the changes I need to do?

Comment: Q: Why are you comparing a list of strings ("listiter") to a single string ("terms.get(i)")???  That can't be good ;)  SUGGESTION: step through the code under the debugger.  Look at both items you're trying to compare.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Can you please tell me  how I need to change it?